# System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having real trouble with this!

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + Fileinfo.Text + "\\Index.HTML");
{
    sw.WriteLine("test");
}
```

it keeps bring up this error,

> System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'

I'm sure its something simple but i would love some help! Thanks so much

Comment: What is the content of FileInfo.Text?

Comment: It's "test12443"

Comment: @SonderSystems `Fileinfo.Text` should be a directory's name, is `test12443` a directory?

Comment: yes, test12443 is a folder name and within the folder there is a file named Index.HTML

Comment: One thing, syntax should be like:

`using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + Fileinfo.Text + "\\Index.HTML"))`

Comment: Yeah thats how i had it before but it keeps just throwing the same error

Comment: Print this variable and share its value:

`var path = @"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + Fileinfo.Text + "\\Index.HTML";`

Comment: is this correct?:
            var path = @"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + Fileinfo.Text + "\\Index.HTML";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + path + "\\Index.HTML"))
            {
            sw.WriteLine("test");
            }

Comment: Just this:
`using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("test");
            }`

Comment: Damn! i tried this and it threw the same errror

Comment: Your correct path should be like this: `C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\test12443\Index.HTML`, you can even try browsing this path first.

Comment: in file explorer it comes up but it just keeps throwing the error in debugging

Comment: Then you definitely need to print the value of `Fileinfo.Text`, it's not `test12443`

Comment: So basically whats happening is Fileinfo. Text is a label with the text from a .txt doc (the directory) and from what i can see it is correct

Comment: Never mind i found the issue in the txt doc thanks so much for your help though!!

Answer (score -1):

Using FIleInfo Also we can get the folder and write the text. Below is the code

```
 FileInfo obj = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\nagajyothy.madala\Documents\test12443\Index.HTML");

        StreamWriter sw = obj.CreateText(); 
        sw.WriteLine("test");
        sw.Close();
```

Here CreateText is for creating the text to file.

Answer (score -1):

You have to manually close `StreamWriter` with `Close()` or use `using` keyword

```
var a = Fileinfo.Text; //test12443
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + a + "\\Index.HTML"))
{
    sw.WriteLine("test2");
}
```

Or

```
var a = Fileinfo.Text; //test12443
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\" + a + "\\Index.HTML")
sw.WriteLine("test2");
sw.Close();
```

Comment: While it does not hurt to close a StreamWriter, it does not answer the OP's question at all.